# jquery - select an element if children not having a specific class

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a selector only solution, not something using `.find()` or other jquery functions.

I wander why if I do `$('.parentClass:has(".childrenClass")')`, it returns elements if one of their children has `.childrenClass`

but if I do `$('.parentClass:not(".childrenClass")')` it returns all elements even if one of their children has `.childrenClass`

Is there a way to select element only if all of their children have not a specific class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wander why if I do $('.parentClass:has(".childrenClass")'), it returns elements if one of their children has .childrenClass but if I do $('.parentClass:not(".childrenClass")') it returns all elements even if one of their children has .childrenClass

Because `:not(".childrenClass")` is not remotely the opposite of `:has(".childrenClass")`. `:not` tests whether **that element** doesn't match the selector. `:has` tests whether that element's **children** match the selector.

> Is there a way to select element only if all of their children have not a specific class?

Yes, you can combine `:not` and `:has`:

```js
$(".parentClass:not(:has(.childrenClass))").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  Should match, no children with childrenClass
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Should match,
  <span>no children with childrenClass</span>
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Shouldn't match,
  <span class="childrenClass">has children with childrenClass</span>
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Shouldn't match,
  <span class="childrenClass">has children</span>
  <span class="childrenClass">with childrenClass</span>
</div>
```

I have to admit that *really* surprised me, as `:has` has a history of not playing nicely with others. Previously, I thought you'd have to use `filter`:

```js
$(".parentClass").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find(".childrenClass").length == 0;
}).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  Should match, no children with childrenClass
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Should match,
  <span>no children with childrenClass</span>
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Shouldn't match,
  <span class="childrenClass">has children with childrenClass</span>
</div>
<div class="parentClass">
  Shouldn't match,
  <span class="childrenClass">has children</span>
  <span class="childrenClass">with childrenClass</span>
</div>
```

Comment: is it impossible to do it in a single selector?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: Very much to my surprise, `:not` and `:has` play together, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for! That's surprising!